# Como mapear uma atributo image pelo Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, fluent-api

Gostaria de saber como faço para mapear um atributo do tipo `image` do `SqlServer` pelo Fluent API.

No meu banco eu tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProdutoFotoERP](        
    [ProdutoFotoID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProdutoID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Foto] [image] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProdutosFotoERP] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProdutoFotoID] ASC
))
```

E criei minha entidade da seguinte forma:

```
public class ProdutoFotoERP
{
    public int ProdutoFotoID { get; set; }
    public int ProdutoID { get; set; }
    public byte[] Foto { get; set; }

    public virtual ProdutoERP ProdutoERP { get; set; }
}
```

A princípio minha classe de configuração está assim:

```
public class ProdutoFotoERPConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProdutoFotoERP>
{
    public ProdutoFotoERPConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("ProdutoFotoERP");

        HasKey(c => c.ProdutoFotoID);
        Property(c => c.ProdutoFotoID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cara, o tipo `image` tá depreciado e vai ser removido nas próximas versões do SQL Server. Se você está começando o sistema agora, é melhor usar `varbinary(max)`.

Comment: Infelizmente é um sistema legado e estou fazendo melhorias nele, se eu pudesse, nem imagem gravaria no banco de dados, somente o path de onde ela se encontra.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Comment: @jbueno acabei de testar e funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A única coisa que você precisa fazer é o usar o método `HasColumnType`.

Note que os tipos `text`, `ntext` e `image` estão obsoletos e [serão removidos nas próximas versões do SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms187993.aspx).

```
public class ProdutoFotoERPConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ProdutoFotoERP>
{
    public ProdutoFotoERPConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("ProdutoFotoERP");

        HasKey(c => c.ProdutoFotoID);
        Property(c => c.ProdutoFotoID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);

        Property(p => p.Foto).HasColumnName("Foto").HasColumnType("image");
    }
}
```

Comment: Agora uma duvida, minha entidade seria um tipo byte[] mesmo? Caso seja, quando fosse salvar no banco de dados ele entenderia isso normalmente e salvaria corretamente?

Comment: Acho que sim, mas isso é outra questão, né.

Comment: Essa era minha principal dúvida

Comment: Acabei de ver, e é isso aí mesmo, você quer salvar um array de bytes. Tá certinho

Comment: Vlw, vou testar aqui e te digo